# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (duplicate symbol)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, xcode7, in-app-billing

I developing a game in Unity and I have used Admob, Facebook and GameCenter in it. It was working fine on iOS until I have added the OpenIAB for in-app purchase, though it works fine in Unity Editor.

I am getting this error in xcode:

> duplicate symbol __Z14MakeStringCopyPKc in:
>       /Users/UmerAzeem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejwaywhkiokzjofdpwnbebkbleai/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBUnityUtility.o
>       /Users/UmerAzeem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ejwaywhkiokzjofdpwnbebkbleai/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppStoreDelegate.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[See error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25jrz.png)

I have tried almost all the solution that I could find over the internet, but still don't understand how can I remove this duplication error, I have tried looking for duplicate files too, but it also went in vain, someone help me out of this, would appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up in your project for:

> MakeStringCopy

And make sure it exists (if exists) only once. If it appears more then once, rename one (make sure to rename it where it being called as well) and try to build again.

Comment: Thanks Roy for reaching out, I have tried these things but none of these worked for me.
I have these in Other Linker Flags, -weak_framework, CoreMotion, -weak-lSystem. Should i remove any of these or add something else?

Comment: @UmerAzeem, with pleasure, do you clean your project before running it?

Comment: As it was suggested in Some posts, I have also tried removing these DerivedData folders, didn't work. Tried removing and adding new schemes, didn't work either.
Also the Enable Bitcode is set to No in Build Options.

Comment: yes I cleaned it. after trying every solution, but the result was same.

Comment: @UmerAzeem Also, search in your project for "main.m" and make sure it gives you it only once.

Comment: @UmerAzeem also, try to remove facebook sdk, clean, build, then add it back again and clean, build.

Comment: I just rechecked there is only one main.mm file in it. let me try to remove facebook sdk and add it again.

Comment: I just don't get it, what's wrong I have tried so many solutions.

Comment: @UmerAzeem Ok, do the following, search for "MakeStringCopy" in your project. Let me know if you find any...

Comment: @UmerAzeem also, are you using Unity SDK?

Comment: I am using UnityAds in it, I forgot to mention it, my bad

Comment: @UmerAzeem can you please make sure you are using the latest version of Unity SDK?

Comment: I have just found a file which is appearing red in the project navigtor, its "libiconv.2.dylib".
Is this the reason of my issue? How can I resolve this?

Comment: @UmerAzeem probably not, but as for that, try to remove it and add "libiconv.2.tdb" instead... did you make sure you use the latest version of Unity?

Comment: I searched for MakeStringCopy like you said, and found that it is in the two files that are giving me errors. AppStoreDelegate.mm and FBUnityUtiliy.mm , should I rename one of these?

Comment: @UmerAzeem perfect, rename one of them, and try to build.

Comment: @UmerAzeem my pleasure, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently face the same issue. I know **Umer Azeem** got the answer but to help someone else who may suffer from the same issue I was in.

According to my application flow I am using printer related third party class to print. To use that I have created object of that class in both of my files `ImagePrintViewController` and `PrintResultViewController` separately and passed required data to it. 

In my scenario I am getting same error with variable name like `_printerSetup` in two of my files`/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../x86_64/ImagePrintViewController.o`
and `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../x86_64/PrintResultViewController.o`.

I have search in both of my file for the above variable name. But I couldn't find that.

After searching long on this I got a idea to **delete reference** of my second file i.e. `BRPrintResultViewController.h` and `BRPrintResultViewController.m` after merging code in my first file.

With this I found my solution and my code runs fine after this.